# Python Error Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, mediapipe, cvzone

I am trying the build a hand tracker in python.

there is my code

```
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8, maxHands=1)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img, flipType=True)

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haseb/PycharmProjects/Final2243/final.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
  File "C:\Users\haseb\PycharmProjects\Final2243\venv\lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe'
```

Comment: Install mediapipe?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install mediapipe in your venv.

activate your venv, then try to install mediapipe :

pip install mediapipe

Answer (score 0):

the setup file `setup.py` in cvzone repo doesn't install the requirements , so you have to do it manually

download this [requirements.txt](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/blob/master/requirements.txt) file and do the following

```
cd [path]  
pip install - r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that mediapipe is not installed in your Python environment.

You can install mediapipe using pip:

```
pip install mediapipe
```

After installing Mediapipe, your code should work correctly.